# What is the Datomic connection string for DynamoDB storage running on AWS via CloudFormation?

Tags: clojure, amazon-dynamodb, connection-string, datomic

What is my Datomic DynamoDB storage URI?

I followed the Datomic documentation for [Running on AWS](http://docs.datomic.com/aws.html) to make a transactor on CloudFormation. I spent a long time looking for an EC2 transactor IP, but apparently the transactor details are written to storage.

So how do I find out what it is? And what's the simplest way to test I can connect to it without risking bugs in my code? Something like `bin/test-connection <datomic://some-uri>` => "Connected to peer just fine." would be good.

(If anyone from Cognitect is reading this, I'm trying to give you money but deploying Datomic is too hard.)

Comment: I have no experience with Datomic running on AWS, but perhaps you can try datomic forum (https://forum.datomic.com) or #datomic slack channel (https://clojurians.slack.com/messages/C03RZMDSH/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Datomic documentation](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/connect), the DynamoDB connection URI is:

```
(def uri "datomic:ddb://{region}/{your-system-name}/{db-name}")
```

For credentials, you can export `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` to the environment, or tack `?aws_access_key_id={key}&aws_secret_key={secret}` onto the URI as query parameters.

In your `ddb-transactor.properties` file you'll have an `aws-dynamodb-table=` property set to `your-system-name`.  If you've already launched your stack, you can review the DDB table name/system name under the dynamo db console here:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home?region=us-east-1#tables:

To connect, you'll need to create a DB.  Here is an example connection from a REPL with my AWS credentials sourced from the environment.

```
Clojure 1.9.0-RC1
user=> (require '[datomic.api :as d])
nil
user=> (def uri "datomic:ddb://us-east-1/jaret-test-name/test")
#'user/uri
user=> (d/create-database uri)
true
user=> (def conn (d/connect uri))
#'user/conn
user=> (def db (d/db conn))
#'user/db
```

I'd also like to point out that I was able to connect from my local machine because I uncommented `aws-ingress-cidrs=0.0.0.0/0` in my `cf-template.properties` file.